# Edit Equation in Extra Objects Add on

Tags: objects

When using the extra objects add on, I can create the shape (sine wave) I want by inputting the correct function.  Once I move onto another object, I can't reopen the options for changing the equation/size of the object.  I just want to add more periods to the sine wave but I can't get the original options for choosing the x and y size.

Comment: Once you create an object and do any kind of transformation (scale, rotate, etc) or if you select another object, the creation menu cannot be accessed again, you would need to create a new object.

Comment: While it doesn't support the extra objects, yet, you may want to keep an eye on the [wonder mesh addon](https://www.blendernation.com/2017/09/27/add-wonder-mesh/), maybe suggest the extra objects to the author.